# dotnet new api -aot returns '-aot' is not a valid option

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using the below command,

```
C:\Users\myUser>dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   8.0.100-preview.4.23260.5
 Commit:    2268e7b15c
```

and then try to create an app,

```
C:\Users\myUser>dotnet new api -aot
Error: Invalid option(s):
-aot
   '-aot' is not a valid option

For more information, run:
   dotnet new api -h
```

I have installed dotnet 8 preview 4 and using Visual Studio 17.0 Preview 1 and trying to use  AOT from this blog post https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-3/#minimal-apis-and-native-aot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating project with AOT template you need to use `--aot` (2 hyphens)

```bash
dotnet new api --aot
```

Maybe there is some missing in that document but you can be sure by this command:

```bash
dotnet new api -h
```

Comment: Yeah, the https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-3/#minimal-apis-and-native-aot was missing one hypen